# Regular expression DEFINE

Tags: regex, pcre

can someone explain why this regular expression

```
/(?(DEFINE)
  (?<alnum>                      [a-zäöüßÖÜÄ0-9-]+ )    
  (?<warranty_word>              (?&alnum)?garantie[*]?)
)
(?&warranty_word)/six
```

only matchs **Garantie** in **Vor-Ort-Garantie**, but this other
https://regex101.com/r/oJKV1Q/1

```
/(?(DEFINE)
  (?<warranty_word>              ([a-zäöüßÖÜÄ0-9-]+)?garantie[*]?)
)
(?&warranty_word)/six
```

matchs **Vor-Ort-Garantie** completely
https://regex101.com/r/axvJmA/1

and also how could I match it completely while still having separate definitions of each part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refer to a subpattern, the substring matched by this subpattern becomes atomic. That's why you obtain only "Garantie" with your first pattern. For each position in "Vor-Ort-", `(?&alnum)` matches all characters until the end of "Garantie", but once in the ground of `(?<warranty_word> ...)` the regex engine can't backtrack since `(?&alnum)` is atomic.

---

Note: as an aside, when you have to deal with characters outside of the ascii range, you must use the u modifier otherwise your pattern and your target string are seen as a succession of single byte characters and not as utf8 encoded strings:

```
# ö is encoded with C3 B6

var_dump(preg_match('~[ö]~', "\xC3")); 
# int(1)

var_dump(preg_match('~[ö]~u', "\xC3"));
# bool(false)
```

With this modifier you can remove Ä, Ö and Ü from your character classes since your pattern is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question.  After some digging, I think I found the answer in the [PCRE documentation](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#subpatternsassubroutines) (which refers to these subpatterns as "subroutine calls"):

> All subroutine calls, whether recursive or not, are always treated as
>   atomic groups. That is, once a subroutine has matched some of the
>   subject string, it is never re-entered, even if it contains untried
>   alternatives

So, this means, in your first pattern, as soon as `(?&alnum)` matches *anything at all* it is used and discarded.  In your example data of `3 Jahre Vor-Ort-Garantie` it would match the number 3.  Then the rest of the match would fail, and it would try again without including `(?&alnum)` (since that is optional), but it wouldn't try that subpattern again.

You could use variable interpolation in your programming language instead, if that is supported.  For example, in Perl:

```
my $alnum = "[a-zäöüßÖÜÄ0-9-]+";
my $warranty_word = "(?:$alnum)?garantie[*]?";

if ($string =~ /$warranty_word/)
{
    ...
}
```

This works pretty much as you want, and it also gives you extra flexibility, since subpatterns can be used in different places.  But it may get messy in other languages, depending on the string interpolation mechanics.